# How to get a unique PC ID via Electron?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

Is it possible to get a unique PC/Device ID via Electron so I can save PC/Device ID to MySQL Server on the cloud? If this is not possible then what other option I have?

The purpose of this to limit how many device they can use Electron App.

Comment: not 100% reliably, but yes, for most users/use cases you can. Hard drive volume serial, MAC address, etc (neither bulletproof). Might look into canvas-based font fingerprinting, it's pretty solid.

Comment: What if you generate a UUID when the app is executed at the first time?. In that case you wouldn't depends on the device and you would be able to identify each app.

Comment: @PieroDivasto Then save UUID on the cookie and MySQL Server on the cloud?

Answer (score 25):

Take a look of the following example.

```
import {machineId, machineIdSync} from 'node-machine-id';

// Asyncronous call with async/await or Promise

async function getMachineId() {
    let id = await machineId();
    ...
}

machineId().then((id) => {
    ...
})

// Syncronous call

let id = machineIdSync()
// id = c24b0fe51856497eebb6a2bfcd120247aac0d6334d670bb92e09a00ce8169365
let id = machineIdSync({original: true})
// id = 98912984-c4e9-5ceb-8000-03882a0485e4
```

You can take a look in this package [automation-stack/node-machine-id](https://github.com/automation-stack/node-machine-id) for more details. I think this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [os module](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os) in nodejs.

You should be able to string together a few of these values to correctly identify unique PC/Devices.

Answer (score 0):

I created a package to for getting the local machine's MAC address, which should be a good way to get a unique PC id: https://www.npmjs.com/package/macaddress-local-machine

```bash
yarn add -D macaddress-local-machine
```

```js
import macAddr from "macaddress-local-machine";
```

```js
// Get the first MAC address
const macAddress = macAddr.first();
console.log(macAddress);
```

```js
// Get all MAC addresses
const macAddresses = macAddr.all();
console.log(macAddresses);
```

returns one of the following or an array of the following respectively

```js
interface MACAddress {
  iface: string,
  macAddr: string
}

// Example object:
{
  "iface": "eno2",
  "macAddr": "01:23:45:67:89:ab"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
var sys = require('util')
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function puts(error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout)
}

exec("wmic CPU get ProcessorId", puts);
exec("wmic DISKDRIVE get SerialNumber", puts);
```

Comment: wmic: Command not found. I suppose that's a Windows-only tool. Not very useful for a cross-platform framework such as Electron...